# Modeling the production of mRNA

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, theoretical-biology, mrna

I have the following example of how an equation for the production of mRNA in a particular organism could look like:

> Consider the following equation for the *production* of mRNA for a gene Y. Gene Y is expressed from a promoter that is repressed by protein R. For example, if Y is GFP above, then R would be TetR.
>   $$
> \beta_{Y m}=\left[\frac{\beta_{y \max }}{1+\left([R] /_{K_{R Y}}\right)}\right]
> $$

And now I am trying to understand what the different variables of the equation are.

$\beta_{ymax}$ must be the maximum rate at which mRNA can be produced and $R$ is concentration of a repressing protein, but what must then $K_{RY}$ be? Is it as simple as that it is an inducer for the production of mRNA?

Comment: Where did you get the equation from?

Comment: At a first guess, $K_{RY}$ is a dissociation constant for the repressor binding of the gene Y promoter, but it's hard to say without more information. e.g. David's question. Also, it is best practice to reproduce the equation as text rather than as an image, to make it easier for screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your post accordingly. In particular, [quotes and other copied material **must** be referenced](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) — this is the standard practice in scientific communication and will also help other users understand the context for the quote. ———  In addition, it would be very poor writing if these terms were not all defined and explained in the accompanying text — please confirm that isn't true ... Thanks! 